# iOS Button Positioning for iPhone 5

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, uistoryboard, iphone-5

my app consists of three buttons that I'm creating programmatically and are positioned right below my navigation bar. The issue I'm having is that while running my app in the simulator, the buttons are perfectly positioned for the iphone 3.5", however on the new larger screen size their position goes down a bit lower. In my code I'm using self.view.frame.size.height-465 as my y co-ordinate so the buttons are positioned in the proper position regardless of screen size. I also don't have any of the AutoResizing masks enabled since I want the buttons to be in the same position when the size of the view changes.What do you guys think I'm doing wrong because whenever I run my program on the iphone 5 simulator the buttons are moved slightly lower.

EDIT:
I'm now attaching screenshots of my buttons across both screen sizes so you know what exactly I'm talking about.

[image: http://imgur.com/Igb5Hdq&UJ1TiQk#0]
[image: http://imgur.com/Igb5Hdq&UJ1TiQk#1]

Comment: use percentages and not hardcoded pixel values.

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: `self.view.frame.size.height-465` <- hard-coding the size of your frame in pixels

Comment: Yes there is hard.coding but shouldn't the y-coordinate change based on size of the screen?

Comment: @iProgrammed I added screenshots to my original post now.

Answer (score 3):

You shouldn't be doing anything in code. If you place it right below your navigation bar, in IB, it should maintain that same distance (because of auto layout) in either screen size.

**After Edit:**

If you're not using auto layout, and doing everything in code, then you should be setting the y value from the top, not height - 465. Just use a fixed value for y. in the code below the frame is set in the CustomButton's init method, and then I just change its location:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    CustomButton1 *button = [[CustomButton1 alloc] init];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(doStuff:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [button setTitle:@"test" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.center = CGPointMake(self.view.center.x, 30);
    [self.view addSubview:button];
}
```

Comment: I'm not using autolayout since I need backward compatibility and also I'm generating the buttons in code, there's nothing in IB.

Comment: Hmm, then what does iOs really change when size is changed if you're using a fixed y co-ordinate. self.view.center.x returns a point, correct?

Comment: @DavidWest, no, self.view.center.x returns a CGFloat (center returns a CGPoint). A fixed y coordinate, will always be the same distance from the top because the top's y coordinate is 0, so you're adding a fixed number to zero -- the screen size doesn't enter into it at all.

Answer (score 1):

```
 CGSize screenSize = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size;

            if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
                if (screenSize.height > 480.0f) {
                    /*Do iPhone 5 stuff here.*/

        myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,129,412);
                } else {
                    /*Do iPhone Classic stuff here.*/ 

    myButton.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,123,412);
                }
            } else {
                /*Do iPad stuff here.*/
            }
```

Comment: Wait, what do you mean? I already have the button created through CGRectmake, my issue it's position

Comment: Hmm, that would work but I'm looking for a solution where I don't need to do this. All I'm really concerned with is the y-coordinate positioning.

Comment: Why Not this is the best way if you aren't going to use Auto-layout.

Comment: I already have buttons at the bottom that stay in position and I didn't do anything different from what I'm doing now.

Answer (score 0):

I highly suggest using constraints as opposed to frames. It will do exactly what you are asking and it will be much easier. Your code might look something like

```
[self.superViewOfButton addSubview:self.button1];
[self.superViewOfButton addSubview:self.button2];
[self.superViewOfButton addSubview:self.button3];

 NSDictionary *viewsDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjects:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:self.button1, self.button2, self.button3, nil]
                                                      forKeys:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"button1", @"button2", @"button3", nil]];

[self.superViewOfButton      addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[button1]"     options:0 metrics:0 views:viewsDic]];
[self.superViewOfButton      addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[button1]"     options:0 metrics:0 views:viewsDic]];
[self.superViewOfButton      addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:[button2]"      options:0 metrics:0 views:viewsDic]];
[self.superViewOfButton      addConstraints:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-20-[button2]"      options:0 metrics:0 views:viewsDic]];
```

Here is a link for the Visual Syntax Language:
http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/Articles/formatLanguage.html

And remember to set all of your controls to

```
button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
```

It may look like a bit much at first but after about five minutes of reading, it's quite simple and makes your application much more flexible.  Hope this helps.

Comment: I can't use constraints, since I need my app to be iOS5 compatible.

Answer (score -2):

1. Define This

`#define IS_IPHONE_5 ( fabs( ( double )[ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ].size.height - ( double )568 ) < DBL_EPSILON )`

2.use this code

```
-(void)viewDidLoad  {
if( IS_IPHONE_5 )
   {
   int newY=(self.view.frame.size.height +( 568-480) )-465;
   [myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,newY,width,height);
   }  
else
   {
   int newY=(self.view.frame.size.height-465;
   [myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(0,newY,width,height);
   }


}
```

Comment: My whole point is that is this required? In my same application I have buttons at the bottom that are positioning themselves correctly without any such code.